# How to Multiply two Column values and display its Result at the end of each Row?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, rows, multiplication

http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1340729929.jpg (Table Image)

Hello, I have linked to an Image (because stackoverflow was not allowing me to upload due to less than 10 reputation) in which you can see there is a Table with 9 Columns and 3 Rows and the Table is connected to the Database and all the values in the table are stored in the Database.

As you can see there is a Last Column of Total in which I want to display the Multiplication Result of Days and Salary values individually Row-wise.

**E.g.**

**user456** has worked **30** Days and his Salary is **100**, so it should multiply **30** by **100** and generate the result i.e. **3000** and the result should be displayed in Last Column of Total **<>amount**.

Similarly,

**user123** has worked **30** Days and his Salary is **250**, so it should multiply **30** by **250** and generate the result i.e. **7500** and the result should be displayed in Last Column of Total **<>amount**.

I have used the following code in the Table and sharing for your assistance.

```
<?php
/* 
        VIEW.PHP
        Displays all data from 'accounts' table
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('connect-db.php');

        // get results from database
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts") 
                or die(mysql_error());  

        // display data in table
        echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>";

        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>No</th> <th>Name & ID</th> <th>Days</th> <th>OverTime</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Salary</th> <th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th><th>Total</th></tr>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['keywords'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['salary'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo '<td><>amount</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 


        } 



        // close table>
        echo "</table>";


?>
```

Kindly tell me what additions or changes should I made to the codes to generate the requisite result?

---

http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1341093148.jpg

I have attached a link of Screenshot. Kindly see the Screenshot and tell me how can I add multiple jobs per user ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
...
            echo '<td>' . $row['salary'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['title']*$row['salary'] . '</td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 
...
```

To add the total of all rows in one column you need to use a variable which gets incremented each time the while loop goes through:

```
    // Declare variable for the place where the value
    // of all the elements of the column are stored
    $Total_total=0;
    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    ...
            echo '<td>' . $row['title']*$row['salary'] . '</td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 
            //Increment the value of the Total_total variable
            //by the salary value of one row till the while loop finishes
            $Total_total=$Total_total+$row['title']*$row['salary'];
    }

    // After the while loop add one more row where the "total's" will be shown

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . Id column totals . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . Totals . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . Totals . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . Totals . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . Totals . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . Totals . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . Totals . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . Totals . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $Total_total . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 

// Do the same for all the other columns where a total count is needed.
// 1) Declare variable ("$Total_total=0;")
// 2) Increment it each time with itself and something you
// need the totals for when while loop goes through one time 
//  ("$Total_total=$Total_total+$row['salary'];")
// 3) Print out the results after the while loop
//  ("echo '<td>' . $Total_total . '</td>';")
```

Comment: Your answer generated the requisite result and now I want to generate total of that Result. So, can you tell me how to get the total of the Last Total Column?

Comment: and also tell me how to get the Total of each Column i.e. Salary and No of IDs at the bottom of each Column.