# php/mysql count search words and result with keywords limit

Tags: php, mysql, search, count

I have the following PHP search script.
When I search for `1234567`, it matches the exact phrase but I want it to match only initial 4 characters i.e. `1234`.

**Explanation:**

I want it to count the initial 4 characters and display the result matching those initial characters. E.g. if someone search for `1234567` then the script should count the initial 4 characters i.e. `1234` and show the results. Similarly if someone search `456789` then the script should count the initial 4 characters i.e. `4567` and show the results.

```
///explode search term
           $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);
           foreach($search_exploded as  $search_each)
           {
           //construct query

            $x++;
            if ($x==1)
               $construct .= "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
           else
              $construct .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

           }


     //echo out construct

    $construct = "SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE $construct";
     $run = mysql_query($construct);

     $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

     if ($foundnum==0)
        echo "No results found.";
     {

       echo "$foundnum results found.<p><hr size='1'>";

       while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
       {
        //get data
        $title = $runrows['title']; 
        $desc = $runrows['description'];
       $url = $runrows['url'];

        echo "<b>$title</b>
             <b>$desc</b>
       <a href='$url'>$url</a><p>";
```

Comment: whats the problem with the script? is it not searching any errors ?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `foreach` with:

```
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($search_each, 0, 4));
    //construct query
    $x++;
    if ($x==1) $construct .= "keywords LIKE '$str%'";
    else       $construct .= " OR keywords LIKE '$str%'";
}
```

Comment: Can you also look into this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282461/how-to-get-multiple-row-values

Answer (score 0):

To modify your existing code to only use the first 4 words, you just need to change your loop a bit:

Change this-

```
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {
```

To this -

```
for($i = 0; $i < min(count($search_exploded), 4); ++$i) {
    $search_each = $search_exploded[$i];
```

Comment: Your code will search for first 4 words. I think he wants to search for every 4 characters in every word.

Comment: @NikolaK. - that's possible, but he did say the first 4 keywords.  In his code, he references `keywords` as the elements of the search string that are split on spaces, so I think it's more likely he meant words.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282461/how-to-get-multiple-row-values

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the top of your `foreach` loop:

```
if(strlen($search_each) > 4) $search_each = substr($search_each, 0, 4);
```

---

Like this:

```
$search_exploded = explode(" ", $search);
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    if(strlen($search_each) > 4) $search_each = substr($search_each, 0, 4);
    // your code
}
```

This code will search for first 4 characters in every word if that word is longer than 4.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. See here - http://koolfree.com/mobile%20engine/search.php?search=0345319&submit=Search - I have the value 0345319 already in the database and it gives the result when I search for 0345319 but when I add 0 or 1 in the end like 03453190 or 03453191, it gives the error of Result Not Found.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282461/how-to-get-multiple-row-values